# Multiprocessing execution slower than serial execution

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to work on multiprocessing but it seems like in my case multiprocessing in ending up slower then serial execution. i tried the below posted snippet and the result for me are slower. i want to use all the processor i have for execution. One more thing, is there any way of boosting up the for loops and the nested for loop.

```
import multiprocessing
import time

def add(a ,b ,c):
    d = 0
    for i in range(len(a)):
        d = a[i] + b + c
    return d

a = list()

for i in range(999999):
    a.append(i)

b = a[2] + a[9]
c = a[3] + a[8]

#Serial
execTime = time.time()
res = add(a, b, c)
print "Serial:    " + str(res) + " Exec Time: " + str(time.time() - execTime)

#Multiprocessing
execTimeMult = time.time()
resSet = [a, b, c]

cpu = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(cpu)
res = pool.apply(add, resSet)

print "Multiproc: " + str(res) + " Exec Time: " + str(time.time() - execTimeMult)
```

Results:

> Serial:    1000020 Exec Time: 0.0912199020386
>
> Multiproc: 1000020 Exec Time: 0.257400989532

Comment: How many cores are there? I.e., what's the value of `cpu`?

Comment: the 'cpu' variable returns 4.

Comment: This particular type of computation could probably be speeded up by vectorization. Have you looked into solving this with Numpy?

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty simple to explain, and a common FAQ: The overhead of starting a new process for each trivial calculation vastly overshadows the benefits from parallel execution, especially in a case like this, where a fair amount of data for each computation needs to be copied from the caller to the executor.

Comment: Then in what situation should the parallel be effective?

Comment: When each process can run independently for a fair bit of time, and doesn't need to pass large amounts of data from the caller and/or back again, parallel execution is definitely going to offer performance improvements.

Comment: i'd really appreciate and example or link because i am still confused over it. One more thing, suppose if i want to execute the same function a couple of is it possible to execute them at the same time. Suppose i want to execute function 'a' 4 time and i have four processors, is it possible to execute function 'a' on all 4 separate processors at the same time?

Comment: That's exactly what multiprocessing does. Anything where the computation dominates over the I/O should parallelize nicely.

Comment: Python documentation https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool seems to indicate that apply (& even apply_async, which however is amenable for parallelization) use only a single worker process from the pool. So, it seems that the processing is only happening in a separate worker process and not really "multiple processes".

Answer (score 0):

This is not that surprising. The `Pool.apply` function is executed in separate process, which means a few things. As the answer by @tripleee mentioned, there is overhead for starting the process, although I don't think that explains everything. (That should be relatively quick, and far below 100ms.)

The second thing to consider is that there is some data transfer required, in this case a list of around 8Mb. That has to move over a pipe, including pickling and unpickling the object.

If you performed a lot more "work" in the function, you'd see the relative difference go down, though the constant factors are similar. For an `add` method like below, I get timing of `0.96s` and `1.09s`. So identical constant factors, but the relative difference is obviously much smaller.

```
def add(a, b, c):
    for _ in range(10):
        d = 0
        for i in range(len(a)):
            d = a[i] + b + c
    return d
```

Comment: I agree with you but the snippet which i posted is just the depiction. its very precise, the actual code which i have is pretty long. the function to which i pass the list along with the other static stuff is pretty heavy on calculation. That program when executed also return the result. Faster in serial than parallel.